# Error in Android video application-start called in an invalid state: 4

Tags: android, video

I know there are some similar problem online,but none of them solved my problem.
I tested on Samsung S3,some post said it is S3 problem;but other app I download seems do not have this signature issue.
Please help.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private MediaRecorder recorder;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private static final String TAG = "MYTAG";
private int recstate = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "on create");
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    //initRecorder();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
    holder = cameraView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    final Button button_rec = (Button) findViewById(buttonRec);
    button_rec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(recstate == 0)
            {
                recstate = 1;
                startRecord();
                button_rec.setText("Stop");
            }
            else {
                recstate = 0;
                stopRecord();
                button_rec.setText("Rec");
            }

        }

    });

    Button button_load = (Button) findViewById(buttonLoad);
    button_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToLoadActivity();
        }

    });

    Button button_exit = (Button) findViewById(buttonExit);
    button_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            //exitActivity();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    //prepareRecorder();
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  /*  if (recording) {
        recorder.stop();
        recording = false;
    }
    recorder.release();
    finish();
    */
}

private void initRecorder(){
    recorder.reset();
    Log.i(TAG, "reset Recorder");
    try{
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    Log.i(TAG, "setAudioSource");
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    Log.i(TAG, "setVideoSource");}
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.i(TAG,e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }

    //CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
    //        .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4));
    Log.i(TAG, "setProfile");
    Log.i(TAG,getOutputMediaFile().toString());
    recorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile().toString());
    Log.i(TAG, "setOutputFile");
    recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    Log.i(TAG, "setMaxDuration");
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Approximately 50 megabytes
    Log.i(TAG, "setMaxFileSize");
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"Recorder prepare");
}

private void startRecord() {
    prepareRecorder();
    initRecorder();
    recorder.start();
}

private void stopRecord() {
    recorder.stop();
}

private void prepareRecorder() {
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    if(holder.getSurface().isValid())
        Log.i(TAG,"surface is valid");
    else
        Log.i(TAG,"surface is not valid");

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "on resume");

}
private Uri getOutputMediaFile()
{
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp/recorder");
    dir.mkdirs();


    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File file = new File(dir.getPath() + File.separator+ "VID_"+timeStamp+".mp4");
    return Uri.fromFile(file);

}

private void goToLoadActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void exitActivity() {
    exitActivity();
}
```

And error Message:

> 09-03 23:33:29.246     790-1140/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
>   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15031)
>               at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2488)
>               at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
>               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
>               at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
>               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>
> 09-03 23:33:29.246  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ surface is valid
>   09-03 23:33:29.246  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ reset Recorder
>   09-03 23:33:29.246     790-1140/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
>   09-03 23:33:29.256  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ setAudioSource
>   09-03 23:33:29.256  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ setVideoSource
>   09-03 23:33:29.256      184-551/? W/QualcommCamera2﹕ Q int android::get_camera_info(int, camera_info*): E
>   09-03 23:33:29.256  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ setProfile
>   09-03 23:33:29.266  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/recorder/VID_20150903_233329.mp4
>   09-03 23:33:29.266  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ setOutputFile
>   09-03 23:33:29.266  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ setMaxDuration
>   09-03 23:33:29.266  10581-10581/? I/MYTAG﹕ setMaxFileSize
>   09-03 23:33:29.276  10581-10581/? W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/recorder/VID_20150903_233329.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   09-03 23:33:29.276  10581-10581/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
>   09-03 23:33:29.276  10581-10581/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
>   09-03 23:33:29.276  10581-10581/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:128)
>   09-03 23:33:29.276  10581-10581/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:117)
>   09-03 23:33:29.276  10581-10581/? W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:812)

Comment: Do you have the permission to write to the file system, declared in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes,I have.    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

Comment: very strange, never seen this kind of error before, maybe someone else can comment on this.